# Undefined variable: id PHP

Tags: php

Can every explain or show me why i'm getting this Undefined variable: id.

The function

```
public function getByEmbedId($id, $lang=null){
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    $embed = array();
    $e = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movie_embeds WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($e)>0){
        $movie = $this->formatEmbedData(mysql_fetch_assoc($e), $lang);
    }
    return $embed;
}
```

And calling the function.

```
<?php

$embed = $movie->getByEmbedId($id,$language);  
if (empty($embed)){
    $embed = '';
} else { 
    $smarty->assign("embed",$embed);
}

?>
```

If someone can help me out it would be most appreciated

Comment: `$embed = $movie->getByEmbedId($id,$language);` Where do you get $id, $movie and $language from?

Comment: `mysql` is long deprecated. You really need to start using `mysqli` or `PDO`. I prefer PDO.

Comment: The code has already told you the clue.` $embed = $movie->getByEmbedId($id,$language);` so how do you get the $id from?

Comment: check/echo the value of $id..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `$id` whether it is set or not before calling your function. Do like this

```
<?php
if(isset($id)) // Make use of the isset construct here
{
$embed = $movie->getByEmbedId($id,$language);  
if (empty($embed)){
    $embed = '';
} else { 
    $smarty->assign("embed",$embed);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Should probably do the same with `$movie` & `$language`.

Comment: Yeah right. But OP got just this `Undefined variable: id` , If he gets `language` too , let him do as an exercise ^_^

Answer (score 0):

when you call `$embed = $movie->getByEmbedId($id,$language);`, are `$id`and `$language` variables defined before ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the variable $id declared before using it in the function.